# Changing date range in javascript with embedded TradingView widget

Tags: javascript, html, tradingview-api

I have embedded a TradingView chart widget on my blog, however I would like the candles to be bigger than the default, and also start from a date that i can define.

At the moment the default is to show the current daily candle.

At the moment I have tried changing all the default settings that TradingView supply on their widget page:

https://uk.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/

I'm not much of a programmer at all, but i do recognise that the section of their code in the middle of the html is javascript, and it looks like that is the section that allows for control of how the embed loads up.

My thoughts would be that it might be possible to add a variable in there to tell the chart at which candle to start printing from, but i'm not sure how that can be coded.

Any help at all would be gratefully received. Many thanks

```
    <!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
    <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
      <div id="tradingview_498fa"></div>
      <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a 
    href="https://uk.tradingview.com/symbols/CME_MINI-ES1!/" rel="noopener" 
    target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">ES1! Chart</span></a> by 
    TradingView</div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"> 
   </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      new TradingView.widget(
      {
      "width": 980,
      "height": 610,
      "symbol": "CME_MINI:ES1!",
      "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
      "theme": "Light",
      "style": "1",
      "locale": "uk",
      "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
      "enable_publishing": false,
      "range": "ytd",
      "allow_symbol_change": true,
      "container_id": "tradingview_498fa"
    }
      );
      </script>
    </div>
    <!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

Comment: I'm not from the finance chart industry, what do you mean by `candle` in `at which candle to start printing fro`?

Comment: apologies Mosh, i should have made it clearer. Thanks for the reply though.

In the middle of the chart, the candles are the data points which make up the price movements. You can zoom in and out to see the price on any given day, price on the x axis and time on the y axis.

The current or last days' activity is on the far right, then looking left you are looking back in time. You can grab on the screen and move the mouse to the right and the chart will go back in history.

Comment: When the chart loads up by default the first candle on the right had side is the current day, but i would like it to be a day further back in time, for example 30 days ago. So the area of the chart is showing a period of time further back.

Sorry, is that a better explanation? thanks

Comment: More clear, yes :) Sorry but I couldn't find an option to do this :|

Comment: understood, yes i had wondered if it might be something that was 'locked down' and unchangeable. Thanks for trying to help Mosh. Appreciate your time, thanks.